# Accessing the calculated deviance from sklearn GradientBoostedRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The `pydocs` for `GradientBoostedRegressor` mention `oob_improvement_` as an attribute.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html

[image]

However what I find in `sklearn 0.18.1` is:

```
print '%s\n' %(repr(gbr.oob_improvement_))

{AttributeError}'GradientBoostingRegressor' object has no attribute 'oob_improvement_'
```

Note that the other attributes e.g. `feature_importances_` *do* appear:

```
print '%s' %repr(gbr.feature_importances_)

[ 0.18573911  0.02802389  0.03824209  0.4526584   0.04772151   0.03357871  0.16121998  0.01518073]
```

So is the `oob_improvement`` attribute actually accessible in some other manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, GradientBoostingClassifier uses all data for boosting iterations. As there is no held out data at each stage, OOB estimates are not available.

An alternative way is to use random subsamples of training data at each stage; this method is called "Stochastic Gradient Boosting". Doing so reduces variance and increases bias, and makes OOB estimates available. To enable it use `subsample` < 1.0, e.g.

```
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(subsample=0.6)
```

In the example above each base learner is trained on random 60% of data samples, and the rest 40% training samples are used for OOB estimates.

See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_oob.html for a complete example.